# Linux Terminal: traffic volume on IP xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have a client and a server. When I click something in the GUI on the client computer, I want to know how much data (MB) the server is sending to the client. How do I measure that? I cannot install anything on the server so I'm restricted to Linux out of the box tools. I have used tcpdump before but I don't think it is suitable for this task - or is it?

Comment: You can save the traffic captured by `tcpdump` into a file and then import the file to Wireshark to extract all the information you need. If you only have access to out of the box tools then that is your best path to go.

Comment: Unless you specify the Linux distribution and release, it is impossible to know what tools will be in the box. You should also consider monitoring the traffic using a third machine which can be configured. That said, `tcpdump -e` shows the length of each packet, so `sed` could possibly be used to filter out the lengths of the relevant  packets and the results totalled using something like `total=0; tcpdump -e ... | sed ... | while read len; do ((total+=$len)); done; echo $total`.